# pagination in angularjs while working with api

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am working on a restful api website and I am getting data page wise already and I just want to add pagination to my project but I don't know how to do that I have more than 300 pages help me solve this issue, I want to provide link to different pages like http://something/pageno.1 and then for 2 then for 3 and so on and I am using api so I can fetch data only in pages not all data at once

Comment: Are you working on  angular1 or angular 2

Comment: Angular js  and i think that is angular 1

Comment: https://github.com/brantwills/Angular-Paging  I guess you can use this for pagging

Comment: Check this plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/ZyoYIznEU7O5VcmibSSy?p=preview

Comment: Taylor rahul the link provided by you is good but in that it ask to add paging.js or paging.min.js how to find these files